# How to make a django model field where the content increases by a unit after every year

Tags: python, django, model, field, auto

Actually I have a student model and a field called grade where i want the grade of every student to increase by 1 after every year

Answer (score 0):

If the grade always increases every year, create an `enrolled_at` timestamp field (when the student enrolled) and an `enrolled_grade` (what grade the student enrolled at).

Example of getting the grade

```py
class Student(models.Model):
  enrolled_at = models.DateTimeField()
  enrolled_grade = models.IntegerField()

  @property
  def grade(self):
    return self.enrolled_grade + (datetime.now().year - self.enrolled_at.year)
```

Hope this helps!